# antlr4 scales not perfectly with multiple threads

Tags: sql, multithreading, antlr4

I have written an oracle sql grammar. It seems that throwing in more threads for parsing multiple files does not speed up things linearly. Instead with more threads the internal antlr overhead grows significantly.
Technically each thread has its own set of sql files to parse. For what it's worth the tests are run on a 2 processor xeon box with a 1 TB ssd and 64 GB RAM.
Atached are screenshots of jprofiler callgraphs.
Note that the actual timings (measured with System.currentTimeMillis()) are even worse - so the suboptimal behaviour is not an artifact of the used profiler.
[image: offending section of a run with 140 sql files using 8 threads]

[image: offending section of a run with the same 140 sql files using 4 threads]

Answer (score 0):

The generated Parsers and Lexers contain static fields (_decisionToDFA, _sharedContextCache) which are shared among the threads. Perhaps locking on these is an issue? You could test if manually rewriting these to ThreadLocal variables helps. You could also make them instance variables, but then the Parser and Lexer instances should be reused to still benefit from caching.

Comment: Thank you for the hint - I'll check that and update the results here.

Comment: I just measured the performance using only threadlocal instances of _decisionToDFA and _sharedContextCache in both parser and lexer. Unfortunately the effects are still the same: with 4 threads the average parse time per file is 2.1 seconds, with 8 threads it is 5.3 (counted via currentTimeMillis)